# How to explicitly tell mypy the correct type of a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, mypy

I pick a value of a pandas dataframe and the type of the variable is string. In a function I return this value and I have annoted the value as str.

```
def get_item_name(code: str) -> str:
    item = df.loc[code, "item_name"]
    return item
```

However, mypy gives me the following warning:

> Expression of type "Scalar" cannot be assigned to return type "str"
> Type "Scalar" cannot be assigned to type "str"
> "bytes" is incompatible with "str"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

Is there a way to explicitly tell mypy that the correct type of variable item is string?

I get the warning to disappear if I use `str(df.loc[code, "item_name"])` but this makes the code look like the value could be a number but we convert it to string, which is not the case as the value is already string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really sure, you can use cast. You should be careful with this, though.

```py
from typing import cast

def get_item_name(code: str) -> str:
    item = df.loc[code, "item_name"]
    return cast(str, item)
```